# How can I write a JUnit test for a JNI call that crashes?

Tags: junit, java-native-interface, integration-testing

I'm working on fixing a JNI call that's crashing at the moment.  Striving to be a good TDD practitioner, I've created a JUnit test to replicate the problem, which it does admirably.

However, by crashing, the JNI call never returns.  Is it possible to write a JUnit test that reports a failure on a JNI crash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch, if your JNI is crashing the JVM, then that's certainly going to be difficult to test from junit.  You can't, for example, hook up a signal handler for SIGSEGV, the JVM's just going to die.

If it were me, I would change this around a little bit and create a simple Java class with a Main that calls the crashing native code, and in my junit test I would execute a new instance of a Java runtime that runs that wrapper class using Runtime#exec.

You can then wait for the resultant process to finish and check its return code - if it's non-zero, there was a problem in execution.

Answer (score 2):

try using the timeout parameter: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html if you are using junit 4, otherwise something like: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html#Exercise_243